# Is the combination of sun and saturn and mars and ketu all together in the fourth House of the kundali considered bad as per Vedas astrology

Tags: astrology

someone told me looking at my horoscope that I have some very bad bad astrology combinations and this forms an evil angarak yog for me.
what is angarak yog?
the person provided me this chart

[image]

Can someone verify if this kind of combination has been discussed by ancients seers in their works pls.and what might be the remdies plzzz
Also it would be appreciated if someone with knowledge of astrology can make some general predictions for my horoscope plss.
I'm worried after this.plss
Jay bhagwan harihara

Comment: Your Lagnesh (Ju) is in Lagna and hence it has power to neutralize many bad effects.. regarding conjunctions in your fourth house many factors like in which Nakshatra and pada they are located.. how close that conjunction is degree wise.. etc matter.. and also Chaturthesh/Sukhesh is also in Lagna which is Jupiter.. so here also it should neutralize many negative effects..

Comment: You should seek remedies from expert astrologers .. every Dosha in Jyotish has remedies and the astrologers are the right persons to provide you with them we aren't .. we are not experts :) Hoping that you will get the right guidance.

Comment: very thnks for the kind information replies rickross and tezz.

Comment: 4th house is seed of mental peace and 8th is efforts and 12th is final results for achieving that peace..All 3 houses are Moksha trikonas.. 4th house is also Kendra and directly shows our psychological peace. Malefics here is not good although dispositor in own house is something good. You may be hot tempered (three hot planets), does some actions in life that may make you directionless and may get sufferings later..However, we need to check divisional charts, Dashas to even predict and suggest remedies for which exact details are required.

Comment: @Tezz correct..But i think Guru will neutralise only in its dashas not always.

Comment: @TheDestroyer yes mostly... we should first know in which nakshatras (and pada) are all these planets placed in the above chart... and then we can get more insight...

Comment: @Tezz You can guess OP's date of birth and time easily by planetary positions for Nakshatra Padas. Sun in 4th house shows midnight birth and Sun in Meena shows March 14 - April 14 and Guru in Dhanur with Shani in meena shows 1996 birth. So, with moon's position it is mostly April 7 or 8, 1996 at midnight. Now you can know Panchanga and Nakshatra padas too

Comment: Ketu in 4H with Moon indicates mental aberrations leading to blunder making publicly. 4H is also causing Argala on Venus in 6H of enemies, therefore it also tends to bring enemies due to your actions out of instabilities. It also effects relationships negatively... In any case, divisional charts should also be analysed.  Mail me for detail reading: sagittariisigma@gmail.com